# Ship app with DataBase iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play

I am developing an app for IOS/Android/iPad that will be linked to a database. I would like the entire database to be downloaded to the user's device the first time the app is accessed and then updated every three months automatically. I was told by another developer that Apple may not allow an app to be downloaded in its entirety and that it may affect a user's storage capabilities. I was hoping to get some info on this from people who have worked with these issues.

***UPDATE***
Based on Seva's answer below, I have a follow-up question:

Will a user be able to download any content from the database? I see that they will not be able to update their database in this manner, but can they retrieve other content?

Thank you.

---

Comment: For a followup question, please ask another question (maybe linking to this one). This one has been already answered. The general response is, however, that users (i. e. apps) are able to download anything whatsoever. What they're not able to do is execute the downloaded data (unless it's a scripted language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both iOS and Android have both limitations on package size and way around those limitations.

On iOS, the packages over 20 MB are not downloaded over cellular data link; but people can get them over WiFi or wire (via a desktop computer with iTunes software). By making an overlarge package, you'll surely lose downloads.

On Android, the package size limit is 50 MB, but you can register additional APKs and download them as necessary (look it up).

On either platform you can ship the app without a database and on the first run, pop a "Please wait" window and download it over regular HTTP. Some apps that I know do exactly that.

The tricky part would be updating. Applications are not supposed to install code. That means - no updating itself. The proper channel for app updates is Google Play and iTunes, respectively. You're free to download and install an updated database anytime, though - as long as you code the necessary HTTP access.

Comment: I see. Thanks. This saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: Just to clarify, I will always have to update via iTunes or Google Play? The app is a spinoff of a website; when I add content to the site I was hoping it would update the app as well. Sounds like it is not possible, right?

Comment: Also, will a user be able to download content from the database?

Comment: Content updating is OK, executable code is not. If the code *is* content (e. g. JavaScript), then it'll update all right.

Comment: OK- so I can develop so the app updates to reflect newly added content and users can also download content. Great!